# Using a script how do I create a text file that contains all of the filenames in a directory C:\sample\?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Using a script how do I create a text file that contains all of the filenames in a directory C:\sample\?

I've seen similar topics on stackoverflow but they are in Perl or VB6...is it possible to this in a batch file in windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple command will do:

```
dir /b c:\sample > out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`dir /s/b c:\sample\*.* > somefile.txt` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: this was close but i ended up choosing the other answer because it contained solely the filename instead of the entire directory path.  thanks for your help though!